# Cann't send token with looping function

Tags: solidity, erc-721, revert-opcode, transferfrom

Sorry, I'm a newbie on ERC721 token. Please help.

I have deployed ERC721 contract in the localhost testnet. I use looping function for mint token and it works.

[image]

[image]

But when I use looping function for send token, it's failed with revert response. This is my code and response

[image]

[image]

What's the problem? Can anyone help me? thanks

Comment: What's the implementation of `safeTransferFrom`?

Comment: like transferFrom, but with address checking. I also use transferFrom function and still not works.

Comment: Adding to @Ismael's comment you are most probably running out of gas when executing `safeTransferFrom` function in a loop.

Comment: @Kadafi There's an error in the contract that causes the transaction to revert. Try stepping through the function with the debugger but there's no way we can solve this issue without the source code.